# Cannot read property 'jQuery3110309118160008342142' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqueryform, jquery-form-validator

Im appending disabled input fields using jquery and there is a button to remove that disabled property. it is working fine with static form but when i append disabled fields dynamically im getting below error on click of that input box or on change of that.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery3110309118160008342142' of null
    at U.get (jquery.min.js:3)
    at U.access (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Function.data (jquery.min.js:3)
    at r.fn.init.i (jqueryvale14b?v=NOVQDySGO89wzMzO5x7mWS4C_uAdynpZe_Lk2y-xEM41:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.<anonymous> (jqueryvale14b?v=NOVQDySGO89wzMzO5x7mWS4C_uAdynpZe_Lk2y-xEM41:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Object.simulate (jquery.min.js:4)
    at HTMLDocument.c (jquery.min.js:4)
```

this is the code for removing disabled property

```
$(document).find("#"+formId).find(".custom-readonly-input").each(function(k, v){
 $(this).prop("disabled", false);
});
```

even i tried

```
$(this).removeAttr("disabled");
```

im getting same error Cannot read property **JQuery_some random number_** of null

the form is dynamically appending and im doing validation also 
how to fix this

Here is the error Screenshot
[image]

Comment: What is the value of `formId`?

Comment: can you not use `$("#" + formId + " . " .custom-readonly-input")` as your selector?

Comment: form ID will be ID of the form

Comment: which im appending dynamically and getting that ID on click of the button

Comment: @Rak_code, what BenM means is, what is the output of `console.log(formId)`?

Comment: that formId is wrapper and custom-readonly-input are input field which i want to enable

Comment: Please share the output, that might be the problem!

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/032oS check, these are form ID's which im appending and https://imgur.com/LUMnzXz this is console.log(formId) on click of button

Comment: can you add your html code?
js is correct

Comment: Are you try [](https://github.com/ngvcanh/validate-form)

Comment: now i got something. it is the problem of form validation, after appending that for im sending form ID and rules and message to validate. there is something wrong, i removed form validation and im not getting that error. but i need form vaidatin